# U Box around a figure in R

Tags: r, figure, box

I am trying to make a chart in R that has a U box around the figure (lines on the bottom, left, and right but nothing up top). For some reason, I always end up with a complete box. Sample code:

```
x11()
par(fig = c(.1,.9,.1,.9), plt = c(.1,.5,.1,.9), bty = "u")
plot(c(1,2,3),c(1,2,3))
par(fig = c(.1,.9,.1,.9), plt = c(.5,.9,.1,.9), bty = "u", new =TRUE)
plot(c(1,2,3),c(1,2,3))
box("figure", bty = "u")
```

The result has the plot properly taking up half the figure and a box around the whole figure, however the box has all four sides.

Any idea what is happening?

Edit for clarification:  Sorry if this wasn't clear, but I'm not worried about putting a box around the one plot.  I will eventually have two plots next to each other and I would like one U box surrounding them both. I have also edited the example code.

Comment: [Looks](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/library/graphics/src/graphics.c#L3095) like you can't for figure/outer/inner. That fact should probably be documented, I think.

Comment: Ah thanks.  Yeah it would nice if that was documented somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @joran mentioned, the `bty` parameter is only respected if you use "plot" type in the `box()` command unfortunately. You can, however, draw the lines yourself

```
par(fig = c(.1,.9,.1,.9), plt = c(.1,.5,.1,.9))
plot(c(1,2,3),c(1,2,3))
par(fig = c(.1,.9,.1,.9), plt = c(.5,.9,.1,.9), new=T)
plot(c(1,2,3),c(1,2,3))
par(fig = c(0,1,0,1), plt = c(0,1,0,1))
lines(grconvertX(c(0,0,1,1), "nfc","user"), 
    grconvertY(c(1,0,0,1), "nfc","user"), 
    col="blue", lwd=4)
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. I just updated my question.

Comment: I want a box around the figure, not the plot.